# PHP Regular Expression to Change Date Format

Tags: regex, preg-replace, strtotime

I almost tried for 10 hours to change the date format suits my needs but couldn't success. I have tried Preg_Replace Strotime functions with following examples.

The current date format is : 02-25-2006
Want to convert to: 2006-02-25

Here are the list of examples I have tried:

```
publishdate = "02-20-2012";  
echo preg_replace("/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/","$3/$1/$2",$publishdate); 

$dateString= '2006-09-14';
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($dateString));



$dateString1= '02-20-2012';
echo date("Y/m/d", strtotime($dateString1));



$date1 = '05-25-2010';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));

$dateString2= '02-20-2012';
echo preg_replace("/(\d{2})-(\d{4})-(\d{2})/","$2/$3/$1",$dateString2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad regexp:

you must mark capture groups in your regexp if you want to use partial matches in your substituting expression! you do so by enclosing parts of your regexp pattern in parentheses. so your regexp should be `/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/`. more info in the  [regexp docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), notably the section on [subpatterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php).

ad strtotime:

if you choose `-` as a date part separator, days *must* come first. thus `02/20/2012` will work as well as `20-02-2012` while `02-20-2012` won't. for more details on supported date/time formats consult the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `date_create_from_format`:

```
$date1='02-25-2006';
echo($date1);
echo "<br>";
$newdate = date_format(date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $date1),'Y-m-d'); 
echo $newdate;
```

Then the output will  be **2006-02-25**.

Comment: I like this solution: clean and takes automatically care of missing/to-be-added zeroes.

Comment: This solution dont work if your string is a phrase or a json stringified